# What does する mean in this sentence?

Tags: verbs, syntax

> 少なくとも十ドルはすると思います。

I didn't get why it is here. Could I rewrite the sentence without する?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「(amount of money) + する」

means:

> "~~ costs (amount of money)"

That is probably the most common way of describing what a thing costs.

> "I think it would cost at least 10 dollars."

You ***could*** say just about the same thing without using 「する」, but **it will not sound nearly as natural**.  For instance, you could say:

「少なくとも１０ドルだと思います。」

「少なくとも１０ドルは取{と}られると思います。」

I would be shocked if they did not teach 「(amount of money) + する」 in Japanese-as-a-foreign-language, seriously.  It is an expression we use on a daily basis.

Comment: 蛇足ですが、「かかる」というのもあります

Comment: "I would be shocked if they did not teach..." - So far I've been taught 掛かる for this purpose.